# How to scrape some contents on a website which was hidden using JS in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am recently taking a course about scraping a website using Python. The website URL is "http://www.kiva.org/lend/742129". It is a charity websites. The contents I want to scrape is about the contributors to this project. And I am sure it used some JS technology which I don't know how it works.

I tried to analyze the html source page but I only find that when I click on the More button the whole page source just changed. So I can scrape the content unless I clicked the JS link. But I just don't know how to simulate a web browser inside the python.

By asking the tutor in my class, I am told whether to use a module called request or another one called mechanize but none of this do the trick for me. I tired to use the module called selenium but it is just so complicated and I got lost..

Is there anyone who can kindly give me some suggestions about how to make it works. I am really a beginner for websites as well as web scraping. And I have no idea at all how to analyze the html and to get the contributors' list out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular web-site has a lot of dynamic things going on. For instance, in order to see the `More` link - you need to scroll the page down to bottom several times. Then, after clicking on `More` you need to wait for it to process. Here's where you can start (well it is actually a working code):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.kiva.org/lend/742129')

for _ in xrange(5):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(1)

more = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_id('showMoreLenders'))
more.click()

time.sleep(2)

# get the lenders
for lender in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//section[@id="theLenders"]//li//div[@class="name"]/a'):
    print lender.text

driver.close()
```

It prints all of the 72 lenders on the page (I would not post them here since these are the names).

I don't find those `time.sleep()` calls reliable, but this is ok for an example - you would probably need to switch to using `WebDriverWait`s instead of having explicit delays.

Comment: I see, thanks. So it is more like simulate the whole process we human navigate the webpage. Quite different from what I have learnt form the courses. Thanks.